# UINavigationControllerDelegate methods are not called

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uinavigationcontroller, uikit

I'm trying to make custom transitions when pushing/popping viewControllers from a custom `UINavigationController` class. I'm implementing the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` method 
`navigationController(_:animationControllerFor:from:to:)`, but it does not get called.

I'm creating a `UINavigationController` in storyboard and putting it's class as `CustomNavigationController`. I'm also assigning it a root ViewController in the storyboard (let's call the root VC `CustomViewControllerRoot`).

Here is the code I'm using (simplified and not tested):

```swift
protocol NavigationDelegate {
 func pushCustomViewController()
 func popViewController()
}

class CustomNavigationController: UINavigationController, NavigationDelegate {

    init() {
      super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
      delegate = self
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
      self.navigationBar.isHidden = true

      guard viewControllers.first is CustomViewControllerRoot else {fatalError("Error")}
      rootVC = viewControllers.first as? CustomViewControllerRoot
      rootVC?.navigationDelegate = self

      //Setup the rest of the viewControllers that are to be used
      customVC = CustomUIViewController()
      customVC?.navigationDelegate = self
    }

    var rootVC: CustomViewControllerRoot?
    var customVC: CustomViewController?    

    func pushCustomViewController() {
      if customVC != nil {
         self.pushViewController(customVC!, animated: true)
      }
    }

    func popViewController() {
      self.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}


extension CustomNavigationController: UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerFor operation: UINavigationController.Operation, from fromVC: UIViewController, to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        // This is never called, even though the delegate is set in the initializer to CustomNavigationController
        print("TEST")
        return nil
    }

}
```

I then let each custom `UIViewController` subclass in my navigation hierarchy delegate push or pops to this `CustomNavigationController` above. For example this is the root vc assigned to the navigation controller. Since it lies as root it never needs to push itself or be popped, as it is presented when the `CustomNavigationController` is presented. It delegates to `CustomNavigationController` when it finds that another VC should be presented on top of it:

```swift
class CustomViewControllerRoot {

 var navigationDelegate: NavigationDelegate?

 override func viewDidLoad(){
   super.viewDidLoad()
 }

 @objc func someButtonPressedToPresentCustomVC(){
   navigationDelegate?.pushCustomViewController()
 }

}
```

The dismissal is handled inside each `CustomViewController` which also delegates the pop down to the `CustomNavigationController` (I don't want to use the navbar for dismissal so there is no "back button" from the start):

```
class CustomViewController: UIViewController {

 var navigationDelegate: NavigationDelegate?

 override func viewDidLoad(){
   super.viewDidLoad()
 }

 @objc func dismissViewController(){
   navigationDelegate?.popViewController()
 }  
}
```

To my understanding the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` method inside the extension of `CustomNavigationController` should be called whenever a push or pop is performed since I'm setting the `delegate` variable to `self` in the initializer?

Answer (score 2):

Your navigation controller should have a root view controller.
And then you should push custom view controller from your root view controller. And delegate method calls

Navigation Controller Code:import UIKit

```
class CustomNV: UINavigationController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        delegate = self
    }
}

extension CustomNV: UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerFor operation: UINavigationController.Operation, from fromVC: UIViewController, to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        print("TEST")
        return nil
    }
}
```

RootViewController code:

```
class RootViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        let viewController = UIViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        viewController.view.backgroundColor = .green
        navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
    }

}
```

Set root view controller as root for navigation controller in storyboard

Comment: Ah alright! Currently I'm doing all the push and pop from the CustomNavigationController itself by delegating to it, but I should instead do all that in the root vc?

Comment: @A.Claesson It's better to do it in your view controller or do some object helper (some animator) and inject it in your view controller (it is more difficult way).

Comment: I added some more code to show you my hierarchy. All the pushes/pops should works but the delegate method in the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` is never called, and I don't see why